# Prove that $\vec x = \vec0$ is an asymptotically stable fixed point for this linear system.

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

Consider the linear vector field $\vec x' = A\vec x$, $\vec x \in R^2$ , where A is an $2$ x $2$ constant matrix. Suppose all eigenvalues of A have negative real parts. Prove that $\overrightarrow x = \overrightarrow0$ is an asymptotically stable fixed point for this linear system. (Hint: use a linear change of coordinates that transforms A into canonical form).

The definition of asymptotically here is $\vec x^*$ is an asymptotically stable equilibrium if it is stable and there is a neighborhood $N_1$ of $\vec x^*$ such that all solution $\phi_t\vec (x_0)$  with $\vec x_0$ $\in$ $N_1$ have $\lim_{t \rightarrow \infty} \phi_t(\vec{x}_0) = \vec {x}^*$.

Could anyone get me started since I am not able to move forward even with this hint?

Comment: Do you know what canonical form of a matrix is?

Comment: $$\left(\begin{array}{cc}
\alpha & 0\\0& u
\end{array}\right)$$ or
$$\left(\begin{array}{cc}
\alpha & \beta\\-\beta& \alpha
\end{array}\right)$$ or
$$\left(\begin{array}{cc}
\lambda & 1\\0& \lambda
\end{array}\right)$$ right?If so, how to transform A into canonical form ?

Comment: Right. Now you probably can refer to the following fact: for any $2\times 2$ real matrix there is invertible matrix $P$ such that $P^{-1}AP=J$, where $J$ is in canonical form. Consider the change of variables $x=Py$, where $y\in\mathbb R^2$ is a new unknown. Can you work it from here?

Comment: Do I need to work with each entry element in the matrix?

Comment: If so, how do I make sure the entries in the matrix guarantee the matrix only have negative real eigenvalues?

Comment: You are supposed to be able to solve the linear system with each of these matrices. Start with the first, can you write a solution? Do you know what the eigenvalues are?

Comment: So just let A = $$\left(\begin{array}{cc}
a & b\\c& d
\end{array}\right)$$ Then start from here?

Comment: Which book do you use?

Comment: Differential_Equations，_Dynamical_Systems，_and_an_Introduction_to_Chaos Third Edition

Comment: You should read section 3.4 and after it ask questions.

Comment: But My real question is how do you set the entries for A which guarantee that this matrix contains only negative real parts eigenvalues?

Comment: I let A = $$\left(\begin{array}{cc}
a & b\\c& d\end{array}\right)$$       Then I find the det(A - $\lambda$ I) ...Then I am trying to look for eigenvalues by setting $\frac{(a+d)+ and - \sqrt((a+d)^2 - 4(ad-bc))}{2}$ = 0...Then, how can I find matrix P since I cannot pinpoint the eigenvalues?

Comment: You do not need to find $P$. You should first read Section 3.4 of your textbook and them my hints. And only after it ask questions.

Comment: I assume the canonical form to be $\left(\begin{array}_\lambda_1 & 0\\0 & \lambda_2
\end{array}\right) $ where $\lambda_1 < 0$ & $\lambda_2 < 0$                          the solution associated with this matrix is $\left(\begin{array}_ xe^{\lambda_1}\\ye^{\lambda_2}
\end{array}\right)$, Am I in the right direction? If so, What do I do next ?

Comment: If we do not find P, how can I map this linear system to my nonlinear system?

Comment: The idea is to treat it symbolically. E.g., if $x=Py$, then $(Py)' = x' = PDP^{-1}x=PDy \implies y'=Dy$. Notice that this "canonical" change of variables fully decouples the 2 independent variables from each other -- $y_1'=\lambda_1 y_1$ and $y_2'=\lambda_2 y_2$. There are lots of really cool ways to think about what this actually means.